# Warning: require_once(dbconnect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, mysql

I have Create Dashboard for user 
`dbconnect.php` this file I have on: Folder1 and Login File I have on Folder2 
Please tell me what was Wrong?

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

// if session is not set this will redirect to login page
if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
// select loggedin users detail
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
```

I got This Error

> ( ! ) Warning: require_once(dbconnect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\XXX\Script\u07\user\home.php on line 4

dbconnect.php is on u07

Comment: is your `dbconnect.php` file located in a different folder, from the code you're showing here? You need to make sure that the path to the dbconnect.php corresponds from the document this snippet is in.

Comment: Yes `dbconnect.php` file located in a different folder

Comment: Ah, yes sorry - didn't catch that last line. You would need to go one step back then; `require_once('../dbconnect.php');` should do the trick.

Comment: this is full link 
http://localhost/TEST/script/u07/user/home.php
`dbconnect.php` located on `u07` 
i also put this code got same error
`require_once('../dbconnect.php');`

Comment: You need to either supply the absolute server path or the correct relative path to your script in the `require_once` statement.  Without knowing what your folder structure is, and which folder `dbconnect.php` is in, it's impossible to say what the correct path would be.

Answer (score 0):

it should be ../../dbconnect.php

Comment: Like This `require_once '../../dbconnect.php';`

Comment: Here as well, why go two folders back?

Comment: Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0):

You have to link to the file relative path. Such as:

```
require_once('../dbconnect.php');
```

Other option get full path of current working file and navigate straight back to specific file.

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../dbconnect.php"));
```

Comment: Why two folders back? It apparently is only one folder back (u07).

Comment: File `dbconnect.php`  located on `user` Folder i also put this and same error `require_once('../../dbconnect.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 require_once("../folder1/dbconnect.php");
```

Comment: what is folder1 in path?

Comment: Same Issue Bro with `require_once("../u07/dbconnect.php");`  Got This Error `Warning: require_once(dbconnect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\TEST\Script\u07\user\home.php on line 4`  dbconnect.php located on u07 folder